# Pages: Can I follow links instantly?

Tags: macos, pages

Im considering using Pages for personal note taking, but one thing that slows me down is having to click "Open" on the pop out dialog for links.

Is it possible to instantly follow the link instead of having this dialog pop up?

[image]

Comment: Which version of Pages are you using?

Comment: version 10.0 (6748)